$\mathcal{R}$ is finite over $L_0[e,A]$
Let $\sigma:L \longrightarrow L$ an automorphism of infinite order, where $L_0 \subset L$ is its fixed field. Let $R$ be a commutative subring of $L\{\sigma\}$. Let
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{R}=\bigoplus_{d \geq 0} R_d,
\end{equation}
where $R_d=\{r \in R \,| \,deg(r) \leq d \}$. Let $t=$ gcd of $\{r \in R \,| \,deg(r) \}$. Pick $A \in R$ of degree $mt$, $m \neq 0$, and $e \in R_1$ which represents $1$. Anyone could explain me why $\mathcal{R}$ is a $L_0-$algebra finitely generated? Thanks
